# download and upload a binary file in javascript

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I am writing a little application. It downloads a file from a url and then uploads it to dropbox through its restful api(HTTP PUT).
Now it works as expected if the file is in plain text, but fails if it's a binary file, even though the Content-Type is set correctly in the PUT request. Could any one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

In Webkit you can use database, it's the only solution http://www.webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/